# Trigger custom event from an iframe to parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I am trying to trigger a custom event and pass some data from an iframe to the parent window. Both iframe and parent window are different domains.

Below is the code I am using in the iframe document for triggering a custom event.

```
var myCustomData = { foo: 'bar' }
var event = new CustomEvent('testevent', { detail: myCustomData })
window.parent.document.dispatchEvent(event)
```

Below is the code I am using in the parent document for listening to a custom event.

```
window.document.addEventListener('testevent', handleEvent, false)
function handleEvent(e) {
  console.log(e.detail);
}
```

But it results in below console error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://testiframeevent.local" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use postMessage to communicate between windows/frames.  I have just had to do the same, so here is the way I achieved it:

In the document contained within the iframe...

```
// sendEvent uses postMessage to send a serialized object to the parent window
function sendEvent( status ) {
    var obj = {
        message_type: 'game_status',
        status: status
    };
    window.parent.postMessage( JSON.stringify(obj), 'http://example.net' ); // change to the domain on which the parent window is located
}

// called such as sendEvent('won');
```

Then in the parent window...

```
// create and add our event listeners
const winEvent = new CustomEvent( 'gameevent', { detail: { game: 'won' } } );
const loseEvent = new CustomEvent( 'gameevent', { detail: { game: 'lost' } } );

document.addEventListener( 'gameevent', function(e) {
    alert('The game was ' + e.detail.game );
} );

// handleMessage is used to receive a message from the iframe
window.addEventListener( 'message', handleMessage, false );

function handleMessage(event) {
    // ensure the message originated from the same domain the iframe is on
    if (event.origin != 'http://example.com' ) {
        return;
    }
    var eventData = JSON.parse( event.data );
    switch( eventData.message_type ) {
        case 'game_status':
            if ( eventData.status == 'won' ) {
                document.dispatchEvent( winEvent );
            } else {
                document.dispatchEvent( loseEvent );
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

and the iframe itself...

```
<iframe width="100%" height="200" src="http://example.com/iframe-content.php">
```